# Copy Paste Cell to Empty Cell in a Specific Range - google app script sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Im very new to google app script and have been playing around was trying to get a piece of code to work. basically i was trying to copy a cell and paste it into the next blank cell in a specific range of cells.

I got it to work! But im wondering if there is a more optimized/better way to write this as a learning moment

```
function pastenext() {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getSheetByName('Questions')
  var r=s.getRange("C8:C17");
  var up = s.getRange("E5")
  
  if (r.getCell(1, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(1, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    }
  else if (r.getCell(2, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(2, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    }
  else if (r.getCell(3, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(3, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    }   
  else if (r.getCell(4, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(4, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    } 
  else if (r.getCell(5, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(5, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    } 
  else if (r.getCell(6, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(6, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    } 
  else if (r.getCell(7, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(7, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    }   
  else if (r.getCell(8, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(8, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    }   
  else if (r.getCell(9, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(9, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    } 
  else if (r.getCell(10, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(10, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yes. Use loops you are just repeating the same statement for 1-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use loop to make it much shorter, from this:

```
  if (r.getCell(1, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(1, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    }
  else if (r.getCell(2, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(2, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    }
  else if (r.getCell(3, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(3, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    }   
  else if (r.getCell(4, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(4, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    } 
  else if (r.getCell(5, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(5, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    } 
  else if (r.getCell(6, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(6, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    } 
  else if (r.getCell(7, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(7, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    }   
  else if (r.getCell(8, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(8, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    }   
  else if (r.getCell(9, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(9, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    } 
  else if (r.getCell(10, 1).isBlank()) {
      r.getCell(10, 1).setValue(up.getValue())
    }
```

To this:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  if (r.getCell(i, 1).isBlank()) { // If the specific cell found is blank
    r.getCell(i, 1).setValue(up.getValue());
    break; // exit the loop after set value
  }
```

The use of `break` is just the same as the `else if` in previous lengthy one, so it will just find the satisfying condition for the current data then ignore the other conditions or the other conditional `else if` blocks are skipped/ignored after it found the satisfying condition.